# can DiracLE change Pitch or just the time Stretching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using Dirac LE. i have tried to change the pitch of a sound but got the following error in console..

[image]

Can Dirac LE convert the pitch of a sound audio? I know i can only use one channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can change the pitch.

please be aware that you need to create and destroy the dirac object when you change something

so:

- create the dirac instance with DiracCreate (or the interleaved version)
- set the pitch/tempo and other settings
- do the processing with DiracProcess
- destroy the dirac instance with DiracDestroy

if you want to change a setting you need to create/destroy the dirac instance in the LE version (calling DiracReset is not enough)

oh, and you can process multiple channels by having multiple dirac instances, however these are not linked/synced and this can cause small variations in left/right channel, resulting in an unstable stereo image

Comment: i am just using the DiracAudioPlayer and change the pitch with it. It works fine. will it create any problem??

Comment: I don't have experience with that set of wrapped classes, but you will see in the read me file that it is mentioned that you can change the pitch after it has stopped playing.  
If you want to change it before playing you need to make sure it is set before the 'preparetoplay' method (in DiracAudioPlayerBase.mm) is called. You will see that it is applied in the 'processaudiothread' method (in DiracAudioPlayer.mm) just before the first call to DiracProcess